# How to update any field in a json of type json? It should accept an object or an array of key(s) and update the key if it exists else create

Tags: sql, node.js, json, postgresql

Generic function in nodejs and Postgres to update a key in JSON column of type JSON in Postgres.

I have tried the below query:

```
update contacts set contact_data = jsonb_set(contact_data, '{order_id}', '${order_date}', '${product_name}') where id = ${id};
```

But the issue is every time I need to specify the keys. I need something generic, something that accepts a set of keys and updates them. The keys may vary every time the function gets called.

I am trying to avoid looping as each time the update is triggered, Postgres re-writes the entire row or at least that's what I know.

Please let me know if you need more clarifications regarding the question.
Thanks.

Comment: What is not generic about that statement?

Comment: Every time I need to update a new key, I need to add it in the query, which will lead to modification of the function and the query. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Use a parameter for the key.

Comment: If you need to do this often, it is a good indication that de-normalizing your model by introducing JSON wasn't such a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Yes, but if we want to update multiple keys then? The keys (and its numbers) can vary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It does not get called often. But the idea is to create a function that accepts any number of keys and update them in JSON if they exist else create one.

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts jsonb data into text so that to be agnostic against the jsonb data structure :

You pass to the function `jsonb_key_replace` an array of old_keys to be replaced by an array of new_keys. The function jsonb_key_replace iterates on the aggregate function replace_agg and the result is converted into jsonb :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace(str1 text, str2 text, old text, new text)
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT replace(COALESCE(str1,str2), old, new) ;
$$ ;

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS replace_agg (text, text, text) ;
CREATE AGGREGATE replace_agg (text, text, text)
( sfunc = replace
, stype = text
) ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_key_replace
( jsonb_to_update jsonb
, old_keys text[]
, new_keys text[]
)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
SELECT replace_agg(jsonb_to_update :: text, '"' || l.old || '":', '"' ||  l.new || '":') :: jsonb
  FROM unnest(old_key, new_key) AS l(old, new) ;
$$ ;
```